# Bookmarklet to Ajaxify a Forum: Technically Feasible?

Tags: html, ajax

I don't know much more than html.

But, can you tell me if this is possible: a bookmarklet that would ajaxify a forum so that posts would automatically refresh/add to the page?

Currently, for most forums, you need to constantly refresh to get new pages. And that's annoying.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have control over the forum (it sounds like it), this will be impossible in most cases. The required amount of parsing and fine-tuning to make this work would be *huge*.

Comment: There's no reason you couldn't replace a particular div with its own contents. No parsing at all if the right elements can be accessible via ID or reasonable logic.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, but you'd still have to identify each div... to make the request... You'd have to know which divs to update... You may have side effects from dependencies that div has/had... It may be possible, but awful to implement if there's no support from the forum owner. Depends on the page structure, though: If it's a really simple one, it might work

Comment: Most forums are displaying a pretty simple list of threads. Refresh the div containing the list. No need to do each individually.